# Vue.js not being recognised with CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I am currently learning Vue.js and I have an issue with it, I am calling Vue using a CDN.

I have followed instructions but it does not seem to be recognising that Vue exists.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vue Basics</title>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@400;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

  <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Vue Course Goals</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="user-goal">
    <h2>My Course Goal</h2>
    <p>{{coarseGoal}}</p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the simple js file It does not output the code from the Vue object.

Would really appreciate any help on this.

```js
const app = vue.createApp({
  data () {
    return {
      coarseGoal: 'This is the best',
    };
  }
});
app.mount('#user-goal');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Vue.createApp` instead of `vue.createApp`.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      coarseGoal: 'This is the best',

    };
  }
});
app.mount('#user-goal');
```

```html
<title>Vue Basics</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Vue Course Goals</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="user-goal">
    <h2>My Course Goal</h2>
    <p>{{coarseGoal}}</p>
  </section>
</body>
```